# Which chapter of the webcomic does Season 2 of One Punch Man anime end in?

Tags: one-punch-man

Supposedly the last episode of the 2nd season of One Punch Man anime is based on Chapters 83-84 of the manga. But how about the webcomic?

Which chapter of the webcomic does Season 2 of One Punch Man anime end in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, the last episode of the second season of One Punch Man is based on Chapters 83-84 of the manga.

With that information, you can easily Google to check the [OPM Wikia](https://onepunchman.fandom.com/wiki/Chapter_84):

[image]

The webcomic chapter is #54.

The Wikia shows you which episode is based on which manga chapter and webcomic chapter. You can also use this site to check for the details in a different order too.